# WebApi 1.0 Action overloading in Asp.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

WebApi 1.0 suports action overloading like thiss

```
public class BarsController : ApiController 
{ 

// /api/bars?h=hello 
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string h) 
{ 
return Get(h, null, null); 
} 
// /api/bars?h=hello&w=world 
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string h, string w) 
{ 
return Get(h, w, null); 
} 
// /api/bars?h=hello&w=world&z=15 
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string h, string w, int? z) 
{ 
if (z != 0) 
return new string[] { h, w, "this is z: " + z.ToString() }; 
else 
return new string[] { h, w }; 
} 
}
```

As I know this is impossible to implement the same logic in Asp.Core Api. So, maybe some one know any good reason why this is bad and not allowed in ASP.CORE  or maybe how to impement the same behavior  ASP.CORE 2.+ ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm right but I think the ability to do it was removed in ASP.Net Web API 2.0 and not something that is "missing" from ASP.Net Core MVC

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: May have been something to do with routing but honestly, I'm not sure. In your example though, you could safely remove the actions with 1 and 2 parameters without any adverse effects. Might be a bad example, but not sure why you want to be able to.

Comment: @volfk because routing in general changed since Web API 1.0 and became *easier* with the addition or routing attributes. In this particualr case though how is *anyone* going to decide which method to call? If `z` is missing, *both* `Get` actions would match. If `z` is missing, why not call the method with 3 arguments?

Comment: I think this is where @PanagiotisKanavos was going, but never explicitly stated it: action params are optional, and in general, routing short-circuits by taking the first available action that can service the particular route. As such, it will always just take your first action there, and never even bother with the others. Even though actions are methods, because of things like routing and model binding, you cannot do things like overloads, polymorphism, generics, etc.